# How to work with data with type {|}

Tags: python

I have a datum with type like this `{1.01787e+08|1.019e+08}`. I want to split it into two values (delimiter "|") and compare the first value with the second value. 
I tried to change its type to list or string, tried to index the value. However, it keeps returning:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'float' and 'float'.

I really appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Can you post the exact code please?

Comment: I'm just trying to convert it into a known type such as string or list for easier index "val = {1.01787e+08|1.019e+08}
string = str(val)
print string"

Comment: That isn't by any chance a `:` instead of `|`, is it?

Comment: what I want to do is pull out the value 1.01787e+08 to compare it with the value 1.019e+08

Comment: "pull out the value" - pull it out from what? Is that a string? If not what is it?

Comment: No it's a "|", I'm sure, it's in a dataset that I need to clean

Comment: I don't know what type it is. When I try print type({1.01787e+08|1.019e+08}) => TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'float' and 'float'

Comment: you cannot do binary or on floats ... try casting them both as int... maybe you want `{int(1.01787e+08)|int(1.019e+08)}`

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I figure it out now :D

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you treat your data as a string: the Python interpreter will not understand that data representation as it stands.

```
>>> data = "{1.01787e+08|1.019e+08}"
>>> result = [float(s) for s in data[1:-1].split("|")]
>>> result
[101787000.0, 101900000.0]
```

The `[1:-1]` trims the brackets from start and finish. The `split` method separates the two numbers, then the `float` call converts them from strings into Python number types.

Comment: good answer (+1) but I suspect this is what he wants `{int(1.01787e+08)|int(1.019e+08)}` which is a set with one element (ofc :P)

Comment: @JoranBeasley I mean maybe... I assumed the `{|}` was just a simple way to markup number pairs in plaintext and wasn't intended to resemble Python syntax.

Comment: I agree it is not very clear :P (although you very well could be right since he mentions splitting into two values)